# Returning records with nil column value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is going on here? In the console this returns this:

```
User.find(2).documents.first.issue
=> nil
```

But this returns this:

```
User.find(2).documents.where("issue = ?", nil)
=> []
```

Shouldn't the second command retrieve the record found in the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `is null` to check for `null` and `is not null` for `not null` in the database:

```
User.find(2).documents.where("issue is ?", nil)
```

Comment: another way: `where(issue: nil)`.  Make it a habit to use key value pair to check for equivalence.  the sql adapter will handle the rest.